# Problem with filtering messages to specific user in android studio application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making selling app, and when you click on item you can send your addres to relatime database. I have no problem with displaying all addresses in recycler view, problem is when I try to filter out addresses for certain users, then i get empty screen that shows no data at all.
I'm getting current user and comparing him with reciver of this message. Variable MessageRel represents relative layout in which messages with adresses are displayed
I'm trying to filter out data in onBindViewHolder like this:

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message m = mMessages.get(position);
    holder.showMessage.setText(m.getAdress());
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if(mMessages.get(position).getReciver().equals(user.toString())){
        holder.messageRel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        holder.messageRel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And this is how my database looks like [image]

I really dont know what am I doing wrong?

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {


private List<Message> mMessages;
private Context mContext;
MessageAdapter messageAdapter;


FirebaseUser fUser;

public MessageAdapter(List<Message> mMessages, Context mContext) {
    this.mMessages = mMessages;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);
        return new MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message m = mMessages.get(position);
    holder.showMessage.setText(m.getAdress());
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


    if(mMessages.get(position).getReciver().equals(user.toString())){
        holder.messageRel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        holder.messageRel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessages.size();
}


public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView showMessage;
    public RelativeLayout messageRel;

    public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        showMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showMessage);
        messageRel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageRel);
    }
}

/*@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(mMessages.get(position).getReciver().equals(fUser.getUid())){
        return CORRECT_RECIVER;
    }else {
        return INCORRECT_RECIVER;
    }
}*/
```

}

Comment: There is not enough information so we can help. What does `mMessages.get(position).getReciver()` return? What is the value of `user.toString()`?

Comment: mMessages.get(position).getReciver() returns value of reciver in realtime database, and user.toString should be returning same that value for currently logged in user. I can post whole adapter if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The values you store in the `author` and `reciver` [sic] properties are the hash code of the relevant `User` object on one specific Android client. Another client will very likely give the user another value, so this is not a good way to identify users.

Instead of using `user.toString()` to store and filter users, the idiomatic approach is to use their UID for that. So store `user.getUID()` and also filter on that.